# Issue with RegExp escape function - Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, regexp-replace

Trying to escape special characters.
I type $ or ^ or | it works fine.
Why is my below code not escaping () {} ? * + and \ when I type these I get invalid expression error.

```
escape = function(value) {
    return value.replace(/[\-\[\]{}()*+?.,\\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");
}
```

something wrong with the above expression???

MDN suggests this

```
function escapeRegExp(string) {
  return string.replace(/[.*+\-?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&'); // $& means the whole matched string
}
```

even this I'm facing the same issue. no error for {} $ ^ | but I get error for () * ? \ +

Comment: They don't need to be escaped because they are inside a `[ ]` (which means they are part of a character class), if the were outside they would need to be escaped to be matched as normal characters.

Comment: So if I have to escape [ ] or ? or * I need to put them outside [  ]. Because when I type () or ? or + or * or \ I get the invalid regular exp error. I do not get that error for {} $ # | ^

Answer (score 1):

They're in a character class (denoted by `[]`) meaning that they don't need to be escaped. They only need to be escaped when they're outside of a character class and in the regex, as they would denote certain operations (like `{1,3}` meaning "One to three times inclusive").

Also a small point of clarification for your question - the code's not escaping `\`, you're escaping `\` by putting two of them together - `\\` is the escape for `\`. So only `{}` and `()` are not being escaped, to answer the question at the top of your post.

Comment: ok I'm really confused Jack!!! When I type {} or $ or # or ^ or | no error is being thrown. But when I type () or ? or + or * or \ I get the invalid regular exp error. How did my function escape $ {} and all but not ? + \